# filter data based on calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table where i have two products and I want to limit the sum of units based on the maximum number of days since product 22 has been out (in this case 7 days) and exclude the units moved for product 55 that exceed 7 days (product 55 has been out for 11 days)

I have tried a calculated field but it doesn't appear to calculate.

i have done a if product = 22 the max(days since release) and the when I do where days since released = calculated field no results come out if I do not show the days since release (in my case I just want to have the two products and the like for like restricted sum)

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for responding I actually found the answer using the following:

{ FIXED [Days From Launch]:

```
ZN(

    IF (NOT ISNULL([prd1]))

        AND

        (NOT ISNULL([prd2])) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)}
```

=1

pretty much wanted to restrict the output (max of one products date) without having to show the dimension and not have any sum showing post that date.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but it is difficult to keep track of your requirements without seeing how the database is built and what is the required result.
Can you share the Tableau workbook or an excel file that will show the design of the database and what would you like to see?